# I am trying to write RSpec test case for a method that calls another method from a different class

Tags: ruby

```
# NodePackageAssetFile

require 'asset_ingester/asset_type/base_asset_type'
require 'asset_ingester/helpers/github_asset_type_helpers'

module AssetIngester
  module AssetType
    class NodePackage < BaseAssetType
      def self.asset_type
        'node_package'
      end

      def self.search_terms
        ["'registry' in:file filename:.npmrc "]
      end

      # Public: Retrieves all node package assets from Github
      #
      # Returns an array of github asset objects sorted by full name
      def self.assets
        Helpers::GithubAssetTypeHelpers.assets(asset_type, search_terms)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# Rspec I tried for asset method

 describe '#assets' do
    let(:nodePackage) do
      [id: 131690,
        name: 'acm-care-management-js',
        full_name: 'AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm-care-management-js',
        owner_name: 'AcuteCaseManagementUI',
        owner_url: 'https://github.cerner.com/api/v3/users/AcuteCaseManagementUI',
        owner_avatar_url: 'https://avatars.github.cerner.com/u/4095?',
        url: 'https://github.cerner.com/api/v3/repos/AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm- 
 care-management-js',
        html_url: 'https://github.cerner.com/AcuteCaseManagementUI/acm-care-management-js',
        asset_type: 'node_package']
      end
    it 'returns the node package assets' do
      allow(AssetIngester::Helpers::GithubAssetTypeHelpers).to receive(:assets).with('node_package',["'registry' in:file filename:.npmrc "]).and_return(nodePackage)
      key = AssetIngester::AssetType::NodePackage.assets
      expect(key).to eq(nodePackage)
    end
  end
```

I tried testing assets method this way. The test is passing but, I want to know if this is the right way to do so. If this approach is completely wrong then please suggest the right way to do it. I tried using RSpec-Stub to test the assets method of NodePackage class.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Paste the code within the question, instead of adding an image of it. Check the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Do you just want to test whether it calls the other method?

Comment: Ensure that there aren't other errors happening, such as `Helpers::GithubAssetTypeHelpe.assets(asset_type, search_terms)` where the name space is very likely incorrect.  You may want to show how you have attempted to test it using `rspec` as well, we will likely be able to spot what you know and what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Message Expectations from RSpec Mocks

In general, RSpec supports testing method calls with [message expectations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/basics/expecting-messages). Message expectations work on test doubles, but you can read more about the full capabilities in the [RSpec Mocks documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs).